# Уточнение перегруженного оператора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть сторонняя библиотека, в которой определен класс `Stream` с шаблонной перегрузкой оператора `<<`

```cpp
class Stream {
private:
    std::ostringstream _buffer;
public:
    template<typename T> 
    Stream& operator<<(const T& t) {
        _buffer << t;
        return *this;
   }
}
```

Теперь я в своей программе для своего класса хочу определить правило записи объекта этого класса в поток. Но т.к. `Stream` не является наследником `ostream`, а я хочу писать в любые потоки, то я у себя в программе определяю шаблонную функцию

```cpp
template <typename T>
T & operator<<(T & strm, const CMyClass & val) {
    ..........  // Запись полей объекта
    return strm;
}
```

Но теперь при вызове

```cpp
Stream strm;
CMyClass obj;
strm << obj;
```

я получаю в IDE предупреждение

> Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Stream' and 'CMyClass')
> candidate function [with T = CMyClass]
> candidate function [with T = Stream]

а при компиляции ошибку

> Stream.hh(112): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion) with [T=CMyClass]

Т.е. мое переопределение игнорируется

Вопрос: можно ли как-то решить проблему кроме как писать две перегрузки для каждого stream?

```cpp
Stream & operator<<(Stream & strm, const CMyClass & val);
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & strm, const CMyClass & val);
```

Comment: Главное вовремя наставить минусов и подать голос за закрытие, что нет минимально-воспроизводимого примера. Только на вопросах с меткой c++ такое наблюдаю

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделал так

```cpp
template <typename T>
T & toStream(T & strm, const CMyClass & val) {
    ............
    return strm;
}

inline Stream & operator<<(Stream & strm, const CMyClass & val) {
    return toStream(strm, val);
}

inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & strm, const CMyClass & val) {
    return toStream(strm, val);
}
```

откомпилировалось